# Flutter Google Calendar Api list Events

Tags: events, google-api, google-calendar-api, flutter

Flutter, Google Calendar API v3
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis

**Works:**

```
  Future<List<Event>> getEvents() =>
  calendarApi.events.list("primary",
  )
  .then((Events events){
    return events.items;
  }).catchError((e){
    print("error encountered");
    print("${e.toString()}");
  });
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
DateTime start = new DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(days: 10));
DateTime end = new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 10));
..
  Future<List<Event>> getEvents() =>
  calendarApi.events.list("primary",
    timeMin: start,
    timeMax: end,
  )
  .then((Events events){
    return events.items;
  }).catchError((e){
    print("error encountered");
    print("${e.toString()}");
  });
```

[image: updated pic]

## Why?

Comment: What doesn't work? could you included any error messages/logging you are getting?

Comment: The only error given is "bad request 400" and that's in the .catchError method, it's at the bottom of that screenshot

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong in this case. I would try using the explorer tool to try and narrow down the source of the problem https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: I totally agree - I use that tool a lot -

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Google calendar API the timeMin and timeMax values must follow the RFC3339 date standard.

Internally the calendar applies `.toIso8601String()` on the DateTimes you pass in. However that does not make them valid RFC3339 dates.

Calling `.toUtc()` before passing them in will make them a valid RFC3339. You can try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/21e2c9d6b799f0b2bf91) togheter with [Googles Api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=primary&timeMin=2018-03-30T12%253A17%253A56.056Z&_h=3&) and you will see the different responses.

There is probably more ways to make DateTime RFC3339 compliant but this should point you to the error atleast.